# Estimate of the perturbation of the spectral radius of a positive matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, estimation, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ be a positive matrix. $B$ is a small perturbation of $A$, and $B$ is still a positive matrix.

By Perron-Frobenius Theorem, it is known that $r(A)$ and $r(B)$ are algebracially simple eigenvalue of $A$ and $B$.
Here, $r(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$.

Is there an estimate between $r(A)$ and $r(B)$ having the following type?

$$\vert r(A) - r(B)\vert \leq C \Vert A-B\Vert $$

for some $C$.

Comment: Actually, I can find some estimates but not in this form.

Comment: there are estimate of the form $C\|A-B\|^{1/n}$ where $n$ is the size of matrices

Comment: @Exodd Thanks. This is an estimate for a general matrix. I have found this estimate.  Here, $A$ is a positive matrix. I think there exists a more exact estimation.

Comment: I think that any non-diagonalizable positive matrix $A$ is a counterexample

Comment: Norm ?  any ? ...

Comment: @ToniMhax it doesn't matter, since all norms are equivalent

Comment: @LeiZhang There are not such estimates. There are 3x3 example where the radius changes as $\|A-B\|^{1/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see Theorem 8 in epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0719030

The key point is r(A) is a simple eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Take for example
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
1&3&2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
E = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $B_\delta = A+\delta E$.

You get (after lot of computations) that $r(A)=4$ and $r(B_\delta) = 4 + O(\sqrt{\delta})$ for $\delta$ converging to zero, so 
$$|r(A)-r(B_\delta)|=   O(\sqrt{\delta}) > C\delta = C\|B_\delta-A\|$$
for every constant $C$ for $\delta$ small enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cannot verify your example. But I can figure out a very easy example.

Comment: $$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&2&1\\
0&0&2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
E = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $B_\delta = A+\delta E$. 

In this example, we can see that $r(A)=2$ and $r(B_\delta) = 2 + O(\sqrt{\delta})$ for $\delta$ converging to zero.

Comment: I checked your answer by numerical method and was sorry to tell you that I found a line. This implies that $\vert r(A) - r(B_\delta)\vert = O(\delta)$.

Comment: I found the answer. Please see Theorem 8 in https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0719030  The key point is $r(A)$ is a simple eigenvalue. Thank you again @Exodd. Your example shows me the way to find the answer.

Comment: @LeiZhang the difficulty was in finding a strictly positive matrix, otherwise you can always take $J$ the nilpotent Jordan block and add $\delta e_ne_1^T$ to obtain a $\sqrt[n]{\delta}$ perturbation.

Comment: @LeiZhang you're right. Write the true answer and accept that, instead of this one