# Positive matrices are diagonalizable in $\mathbb C$?

Tags: diagonalization, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix with real positive entries. Is it true that it is diagonalizable in $\mathbb C$?

My guess is that it is false, but the counterexample can't be a $2\times 2$ matrix, since I checked that the conditions on trace and determinant lead to an absurd.

Is there a well-known counterexample? Like something that comes from Markov Chains or Dynamical Systems?

(it comes from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932793/estimate-of-the-perturbation-of-the-spectral-radius-of-a-positive-matrix) question on perturbations of matrices)

Comment: Complementary question: Is there any $2n \times 2n$ convenient matrix?

Comment: @Maam at this point, I think that following the same example of the answers below, there are. Probably there's one that has 1 everywhere except the last row

Comment: @Exood, I will gladly share your idea  if somebody gives an example. For the moment, I am suspicious  :)

Comment: @Maam Post a new question ;), and add the link here

Comment: You cannot get a $2\times 2$ example because by the Perron-Frobenius theorem, a positive matrix has a simple eigenvalue, so in this case the two eigenvalues are different and the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you Jose, the case 2x2 is clear. I posted a question right now, looking forward to all answers and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After computation the counter-example is $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\6&2&8\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Could you include the characteristic polynomial? It seems like it must have the form $x^2(x-a)$ for some positive $a$, right?

Comment: Yup $x^2(x-11)$ as obvious

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, derived from the "telephone matrix":
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\1&2&3\end{pmatrix}$$
Its characteristic polynomial is given by $t^2(t-9)$.