# Do any even-order square non-diagonalizable matrices with strictly positive entries exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Could one provide an example of a non-diagonalizable $2n\times 2n$ matrix with strictly positive entries, or prove that such matrix doesn't exist?

Every $2\times 2$ matrix with strictly positive entries is diagonalizable. One can prove it starting with one double eigenvalue, from where one off-diagonal entry necessarily equals $0$, contradiction.

My computations (without exact proof for the moment) show that e.g. a $(2n+1)\times (2n+1)$ matrix, where the rows $r_i=r_j$ for $i,j\neq n+1$  is non-diagonalizable.

I have no answer for the matrices of order $2n\times 2n, n>1.$

**Motivation**

My question is inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932855/positive-matrices-are-diagonalizable-in-mathbb-c), and a research I did with special square matrices with positive entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&4&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It has rank 2, but the only eigenvalue different from zero is 5, that is simple since it is the spectral radius (Perron-Frobenius), so it lacks a zero eigenvector.

Comment: Right! Thank you, Exodd, it's quickly decided. What surprises me: permuting 2 and 4 in the last row, the matrix becomes diagonalizable.

Comment: yes, it does. Actually I computed the matrix putting all entries equal to 1 except the last row, and if you call $a,b,c,d$ the entries in the last row in order, you obtain $3d = a+b+c$ as a necessary condition for the non-diagonalizability

Comment: well done, thanks.